# How to add or copy and paste a file in Tizen file manager?

Tags: tizen, tizen-web-app, tizen-native-app, tizen-emulator, tizen-web-simulator

I am new at Tizen. How to put my files, which are in my pc, to Tizen file manager, so I can access my custom photos, videos, apps from Tizen emulator.

Answer (score 2):

In the connection explorer of Tizen Studio, select the emulator you want to use. Then go to the **opt->usr->media->Images** directory of that and click right on that directory to select the option **Push the file**. It'll provide you the file browsing facility. Select the file you want to push from there.

Now, find the file in emulator's file manager(in the Images directory). Have a look on the image below:
[image]

Comment: Hi, what's the status right now? Are you able to do this?